# Dual gravity for a fluid simulation (looping animation)

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

[image]

I'm working on this looping animation. When the character falls backwards I want the fluid sim to splash upwards as usual. I've set this up and it's pretty straightforward. What I'm struggling with is, I want a separate, "anti-gravity" fluid sim that splashes in the downward direction as the character passes through the upside down portion. The trick is, I want each splash to stay in its "zone", so no part of the upper splash falls into the upside-down, and vice versa.

Should this be set up as two separate simulations, or can it be done all in one sim? What parameters should I use? The gravity of the domain?

Comment: Were you able to do it? I think two different sims would achieve the effect. The domain boundaries of each simulation would prevent the splash from entering the opposite simulation's boundaries as long as you specify manually where the boundary is.